# How to pass a variable to a method in button clickListener event?

Tags: java, vaadin7, clicklistener

I have a button with a ClickListener event and a method inside. The method is responsible for adding a new row in Vaadin GirdLayout once a button is clicked.

```
private GridLayout buildDeductionsGrid(){
        GridLayout deductionsGrid = new GridLayout(13, 8);

        deductionsGrid.setSpacing(true);
        deductionsGrid.setWidth("50%");

        addDeductionsGridLabelsAndFields(deductionsGrid);

        return deductionsGrid;
    }
```

This method creates a grid for rows to be inserted.

```
private void addDeductionsGridLabelsAndFields(GridLayout deductionsGrid) {
    int rowIndex = 1;

    btnAddDeductionRow.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) event -> addNewDeductionRow(deductionsGrid, rowIndex));
}
```

`rowIndex` as it's name suggests is index of a row which needs to be incremented in `addNewDeductionRow` method. It increments without a problem the first time the button is clicked but it doesn't *save* the incrementation so when the button is clicked the second time, it tries to add a row at the same place when the button was clicked first.

```
private void addNewDeductionRow(GridLayout deductionsGrid, int rowIndex) {
        String cbValue = deductionTypeDropdown.getValue().toString().toLowerCase();

        for (DeductionsGridRow deductionsGridRow : deductionsGridRows) {
            if (deductionsGridRow.getDeductionType().getName().toLowerCase().equals(cbValue)) {
                deductionsGrid.addComponent(deductionsGridRow.getGridRowLabel(), 0, rowIndex);

                deductionsGrid.addComponent(new Label("Amount"), 1, rowIndex);
                deductionsGrid.addComponent(deductionsGridRow.getAmount(), 2, rowIndex);
            }
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }
```

This method does what it says - adds a new row.

Note: `deductionsGrid` and `rowIndex` are marked as final; I am using Vaadin 7.6.2

Comment: Can you show more of the code? To me it looks like your `rowIndex` is a local variable. As such, it would only be known in its local scope and each method invocation creates its own new `rowIndex = 1`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: How is the row added? Either use no index at all to always append at the end or use a row index (of the button?) and insert the new row at the button's position?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be enough. Edited the question and expanded on the example. @ifloop the button is in its own row so it does not move.

Comment: Your rowIndex variable is just a local variable in your `addNewDeductionRow` method, so naturally it will be gone when your method ends. Make it an instance varaible.

Comment: Yeah... My mistake was having `rowIndex` inside the function and not the class itself... Rookie mistake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your always passing `1` as the rowIndex into your function. The incrementation inside the function does not change the value outside of the function (and even if it would, 'outside' it is just another variable with local scope)

Maybe try to determine the rowIndex dynamically using [GridLayout#getRows](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/7.7.3/com/vaadin/ui/GridLayout.html#getRows--).

**EDIT** after comment

If the getRows() function always returns the predetermined grid size, then maybe the GridLayout itself is the problem here. It seems that it is intended to be used for laying out given content. When you are creating/changing content dynamically a list or table or some iterating component may be the right tool here

Comment: I have tried that but it always gives the same amount of rows, even when there are no rows present. I think it is like that because of the GirdLayout has a predetermined size of 8